# Generar Alert De Bootstrap Con JQUERY

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Intento enviar una peticion ajax la cual necesito que cuando me devuelva la respuesta en el .done(function(->respuesta<-){
me aparezca [image: un mensaje de alert en mi vista de esta manera.]

como puedo hacer esa validacion en el done para que me aparezca esa "alertica" en mi vista??
gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sería bueno que agregaras un poco de tú código o explicaras mejor, tal vez no queda claro. En todo caso, si lo único que quieres es agregar un alert de bootstrap dentro de tu respuesta, lo único que tienes que hacer es crear el div con las clases.

```
$.ajax({
//tu configuración ajax [...]
}).done(function(resp){
tpl = '<div class="alert alert-warning">'+resp+'</div>';
$('.contenedor').html(tpl) //puedes usar before o after si lo quieres posicionar con respecto a otro elemento

});
```

Si entendí bien tu pregunta, eso sería lo que necesitas. el elemento ".contenedor" lo puse por suponer, allí iria el elemento sobre el cual quieres agregar el mensaje.

Comment: Excelente gracias...!!